# Merge 2 arrays of different data types

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was speaking with a coworker today who had just given a whiteboard exam to a potential employee (who did not get an offer) and it made me wonder if I could solve this problem given to an entry level prospect.

Well I couldn't.

The problem is this... Merge two sorted arrays into a single array.

```
arrayOne = ['a', 'b', 'c', ...'z']
arrayTwo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...100]

result = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', ...26, 'z', 27, 28, ...100]
```

The idea here is that

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
...
z = 26
```

I've looked around and can't find a simple solution to this. Keep in mind we're primarily JavaScript, but the potential employee can use any language they choose in the interview.

My sad excuse of an attempt:

```
function merge_arrays(arr1, arr2) {
    let result = [];
    let i1 = 0;
    let i2 = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length + arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i1] > arr2[i2]) {
            result.push(arr2[i2]);
            i2 += 1;
        } else {
            result.push(arr1[i1]);
            i1 += 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
// returns ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", undefined, undefined, ...undefined]
```

Here's a scenario where you can't just take the next index and assume it's in the correct spot.

```
array1 = ["a", "c", "d", "e"];
array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
// should return ["a", 1, 2, "c", 3, "d", 4, ...13]
```

Comment: If `a = 1`, would `['a', 1, 'b', 2, ...]` be a valid solution as well? What have you tried? What _specifically_ do you need help with? Stack Overflow isn't Coding Golf, nor a code-writing service. You're expected to make _some_ effort to solve the problem, and share your results as well as your difficulties, so that answers can focus on what specifically you need help with.

Comment: How is this a "sad excuse"?  You still haven't posted a clear, applicable (to SO) problem with your code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho updated my post a bit, and yes, that would also be a valid solution. I've seen another example of somebody converting everything to a HashMap as well, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: @alfasin: that doesn't look like the same problem. Zipping an array results in arrays of tuples. Here, the two arrays are merged into a new array of singlets.

Comment: @itsclarke: seems like your code is pretty close. Depends on how Javascript (which I don't use) handles an index-out-of-range condition, i.e. what does `arr1[i1] > arr2[i2]` evaluate to when one of those indexes is beyond the end of the array? At the end of the day, it should just be a basic merge sort, with a slight tweak to make the numbers and characters comparable (i.e. `'a'` is normally going to evaluate to `97`, when you want it to evaluate to `1`)

Comment: Is this supposed to be a merge? Or is it supposed to just interleave? What would the expected output be if the arrays were `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `[a,c,e,g,i,k]`?

Answer (score 0):

A solution in TypeScript is:

```
var arrayOne: number[] = [];
for (var i = 1; i<=100; i++) arrayOne.push(i);
var arrayTwo: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];


var max = Math.max(arrayOne.length, arrayTwo.length);

var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < max; i++){
    if (arrayTwo[i])
        result.push(arrayTwo[i]);
    if (arrayOne[i])
        result.push(arrayOne[i]);
}

console.log(result)
> [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd', 5, 'e', 6, ..., 26, 27, 28, ..., 100]
```

one can add an if to check which should be added first, but seemed verbose to add since its not specified.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, it just iterates both arrays and only adds elements to the new "merged" array if they exist (might want to check for null or undefined if `0` or `''` can be present).

```js
function merge(a1, a2) {
    const merged = Array(a1.length + a2.length);
    let index = 0, i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
    while (i1 < a1.length || i2 < a2.length) {
      if (a1[i1] && a2[i2]) {
        const item1 = a1[i1];
        const item2 = a2[i2].charCodeAt(0)-96;
        merged[index++] = (item1 < item2) ? a1[i1++] : a2[i2++]
      } 
      else if (a1[i1]) merged[index++] = a1[i1++];
      else if (a2[i2]) merged[index++] = a2[i2++];
    }
    return merged;
}

// Array with characters always passed as 2nd array
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const array2 = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const result = merge(array1, array2);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I accepted this, but then I noticed a bug... see edit

Comment: @itsclarke ah sorry didn't understand the question, here is the revised answer. Note the second array is always the one with characters in this case. It should be trivial to switch it if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a concat on array like this

```
let newArray = [].concat(arr1,arr2)
```

arr1 and arr2 can have different types.